# SSL certificate not valid because wildcard doesn't match subdomain with hyphen?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a domain like this: `https://abc-.domain.com/`. If I open this site different browser are showing me different results. E.g. Firefox throws the error security risk. Chrome on the other side loads the site without issues.

If I call the domain `https://abc.domain.com` the site is opened in Firefox without issues. So the only difference I can see is the hypen `-`.

The certificate should be valid for the following subdomains/domains:

`*.domain.com`, `domain.com`

I tried to verfiy the certificate with `openssl s_client -debug -connect abc-.domain.com:443` and can't find something wrong.

So is the hyphen not a valid wildcard character?

Comment: Hard to tell without having the real domain name and not just an example. In general `*` includes `-`. But, `abc-.domain.com` is invalid anyway since a hostname must end with a letter or number and must not end with a `-`. See [restrictions on valid hostnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_hostnames).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks for your response. Since they don't want to change the name now I can't validate your approach, but I think this will be the reason. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: FYI `openssl s_client` by default doesn't check the name(s) in the cert at all; it would accept even a cert for `xyz.wrong.invalid`. (This is partly because only _some_ SSL/TLS protocols _have_ a hostname, like HTTPS; for example SNMPS and FTPS may not.) You must add `-verify_hostname $host` to get any checking -- and then it applies RFC952+IDNA restrictions only for wildcard names, which yours is. But what OpenSSL does is irrelevant for browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As detailed by @SteffenUllrich in the comments, hostnames may contain a hyphen-minus (`-`) but this character may not appear either at the beginning or end of a hostname e.g.:

*ex. Correct use of `-`*

```
sub-domain.example.com
```

*ex. Incorrect use of `-`*

```
-subdomain-.example.com
```

The cited [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_hostnames) provides a direct link to [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952), which states:

> A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
> to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
> sign (-), and period (.)

And regarding your particular case:

> The last character must not be
> a minus sign or period.